# $A \in M_3(\mathbb Z)$ be such that $\det(A)=1$ ; then what is the maximum possible number of entries of $A$ that are even ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, determinant

Let $A \in M_3(\mathbb Z)$ be such that $\det(A)=1$ ; then what is the maximum possible number of entries of $A$ that are even ?

Comment: Consider the ring homomorphism $f$ from $M_3(\Bbb{Z})$ to $M_3(\Bbb{Z}_2)$ that reduces all the entries modulo two. What can you say about the rank of $f(A)$? What does that tell you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: How many non-zero entries will there need to be in $f(A)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Umm , I don't know ; I don't know how even rank of $f(A)$ is related to that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many entries in $3\times 3$ matrix with integer entries and determinant equal to $1$ can be even?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042821/how-many-entries-in-3-times-3-matrix-with-integer-entries-and-determinant-equa)

Comment: In general for $n\times n$ matrix  it will be $n^2-n$..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clearly $I_3$ is an example where we can have $6$ even entries with $\det(A)=1$, if there are $7$ or more even entries then there must be at least one row having all entries as even integers, expand the $\det$ along that row, you'll get an even $\det(A)$, which is a contradiction. Thus maximum even entries possible are $6.$

Comment: In general for $n\times n$ matrix  it will be $n^2-n$..