# Example of an $n\times n$ matrix with odd entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , $n\ge 3 $ . Give an example of a matrix $B\in\mathcal{M}_{n}\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ with $\det(B)=1$ that has as many odd numbers as possible.

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: See this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042821/how-many-entries-in-3-times-3-matrix-with-integer-entries-and-determinant-equa) for minimal number of odd entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose two rows of the matrix consist of all odd numbers. Then subtracting one of these rows from the other does not change the determinant. However, since the matrix now has a row of entirely even numbers its determinant must be even, a contradiction.

The upper bound of $n^2-n+1$ odd numbers can be attained by a similar idea. Start with the identity matrix and then make all entries of the top row equal to 1. The determinant of this matrix remains equal to $1$ when the first row is now added to all the other rows, thus making all entries odd except for $n-1$ entries on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=3$ the maximal number of odd entries is $7$, and an example is given by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 2 \cr 2 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $\det(A)=1$. Because of the rule of Sarrus not all entries can be odd, because otherwise $\det(A)$ would be even as a sum of six odd terms, a contradiction. A similar argument also works for $8$ odd entries.
Try to generalize this.